# Call javascript function by creating a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a function by creating a html table.
The function I want to call is called setHooks.
more precisely this time I want to call the function (setHooks) if my table parts was added so the function can check if the checkbox needs a hook
HTML

`'<td><form action=""><div class="myClass"><label><input type="checkbox" name="box'+index+'" '+setHooks('daten.identification','MyBox'+pageForBoxes+''+index) id="MyBox'+pageForBoxes+''+index+'" value="'+daten.identification+'" > Anzeigen</label></div></form></td></tr>');`

thats what I tried but it won't work can u help me please ?

JS

```
` function setHooks(id,myBox){

if(boxArr.indexof(id) != -1){
    $(myBox).attr('checked', true)
}


}`
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to call a function by creating a html table.`

Comment: so when the row was added to the table it I want it to call the function so it can check if the checkbox need to get a hook

Comment: Could you please add your JS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `script` tag at the end of `td`:

```
<td>
    <form action="">
        <div class="myClass">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="MyBox'+pageForBoxes+ ''+index+ '" value="'+daten.identification+ '"> Anzeigen
                </label>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        setHooks('daten.identification','MyBox' + pageForBoxes + '' + index); // Call it here
    </script>
</td>
```